# information not added to realtime database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase



class addViewController: UIViewController {

var refrelation : DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var relation: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dOB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refrelation = Database.database().reference().child("FirstName");
    }

    func addName() {
        let key = refrelation.childByAutoId().key
        let relationn = [ "id":key,"firstName": firstName.text! as String,
                          "lastname" : lastname.text! as String,
                          "Relation": relation.text! as String,
                          "DOB": dOB.text! as String]
        refrelation.child(key!).setValue(relationn)
    }
```

this is code for the addviewcontroller.swift, when I run the app, and the person adds a persons data, it does not get stored on the database?

[when i add people through the app it the information doesnt get stored on the database why is that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVr6.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVr6.png)}

Comment: The first thing to do is check the logging output of your app, specifically when the `refrelation.child(key!).setValue(relationn)` runs. With your current code any non-fatal errors will be written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `addName()` anywhere.

Try to insert the source code working with database inside the `addName(_ sender: UIButton)`, for example:

```
@IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addName()
}
```

Comment: god bless your soul, this fixed my problem. Thank you!